# in JSON in vs-code, how can I give strings in arrays a different color than strings in objects?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, grammar

I want to be able see where arrays are and where objects are at a glance, therefor I would like to give strings in arrays a different highlighting than strings in objects. Is this possible, and if so, how can I do this?

example

```
{
    "A": "a1",              //A=red, a1=red
    "B": [                  //B=red
        "C": "c1",          //C=blue, c1=red
        "D": {              //D=blue
            "E": "e1"       //E=red, e1=red
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [current JSON grammar](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/json/syntaxes/JSON.tmLanguage.json) this is not possible because although there is a difference between keys and other strings, there is none between strings in objects and strings in arrays.

if this distinction would be there, the coloring could be changed with an `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` entry in settings.json. see [Visual Studio Code Themes](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes)